# Redefining \input with itself leads to unexpected behaviour

Tags: macros, input, xparse

I am trying to intercept calls to `\input` and branch of functionality for some filetypes. However, I have run into the following strange error:

Consider the M(n)WE given below, where the macro `\input` has been redefined in a mostly unobtrusive and simple way.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\let\oldinput=\input

\RenewDocumentCommand{\input}{ o }{
    \message{*** DEBUG: (#1)}
    \oldinput{#1}
}

\usepackage{tikz}



\begin{document}
Just some random content.
\end{document}
```

When I try to load the `tikz` package, compilation halts with the following error message:

```bash
pdflatex mwe
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
*** DEBUG: (-NoValue-)

! LaTeX Error: File `-NoValue-.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)
```

Of course, the `~NoValue~.tex` originates from the `xparse` argument specification. In previous versions, I had specified `\RenewDocumentCommand{\input}{m}{...}`, but then the error message is even less clear and requests a file `p.tex`.

This error is not related to `tikz` in particular, I can produce it with various other packges, e.g. `lipsum`.
Going through these respective packages, I could not find calls to `\input` without arguments.

So there are some points I fail to see and understand:

1. Why is no argument passed to `\input` in those particular instances?
2. Why does it work sometimes, e.g. in document body?
3. Am I doing something obviously wrong (aside from hooking into a core macro)?
4. How can I try to debug this issue further (but this is mostly related to 1. again)?

Comment: The `\input` control sequence also works this way: `\input file.tex` (and then a `m` type argument is just `f`, your `p` comes from something named `pgf…`). This syntax is used almost everywhere with PGF/TikZ. You can't replicate this with just `xparse`. By the way, your log file already contains all loaded files. `o` expects a `[`, if it's not there its optional argument is the special `-NoValue_`.

Comment: Before I saw @Qrrbrbirlbel 's comment, I was going to ask how exactly you checked `tikz` never used `\input` without an argument because it is littered with cases of `\input` without an argument-in-the-sense-\RenewDocumentCommand-understands.

Comment: If you do `\input{file}`, according to your definition you get `\message{*** DEBUG: {#1} \oldinput{-NoValue-} {file}`. So ***every*** `\input` instruction will fail and Ti*k*Z is not directly involved.

Comment: The `p.tex` is presumably because it is picking up the first letter of the file name i.e. `\input p......tex` but it's not braced, so the argument is just `p` and the `.tex` is the default extension.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I was neither aware nor did I spot the syntax you mentioned. Sorry for the oversight.
@cfr I have only gone through other packages, and seem to have missed looking into ``tikz`` directly. Sorry for the overstatement.
I understand now thanks to your help what is going wrong, now I need to find a way to define my custom ``\input`` to act on the whole token afterwards without curly braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX does what you asked for. With your definition, any instruction

```
\input{file}
```

will result in

```
\message{*** DEBUG: (-NoValue-)} \oldinput{-NoValue-} {file}
```

because that's what you get if there is no optional argument.

Suppose we do

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{o}{...#1...}
```

The, upon processing `\foo`, TeX will test whether the following token is `[` (skipping spaces). In case it is, it will determine that an optional argument is present, so it will go to the matching `]` so as to catch the argument and will replace `#1` with it. By rule, if no `[` follows and the argument is specified with `o`, the special string `-NoValue-` will be used for `#1`.

You want a normal `m`andatory argument, but it's not the best way to add actions to `\input`, because it can break other constructs. Why? Because the original `\input` primitive is a bit weird as it had to cope with several operating systems and their idiosyncrasies. The primitive expects *no brace* after it and looks up for the file name expanding tokens until finding something that's not expandable and is not a character (after macro expansion). Thus the LaTeX redefinition of `\input` looks for a brace and if it doesn't find it, LaTeX switches to the original primitive. Since it's (unfortunately) possible that packages use `\input filename`, a further redefinition of `\input` should take care of this issue.

<sup>In recent implementations of the engines, the primitive `\input` actually does a check for a following brace, but it's a behavior we cannot count on.</sup>

As a general advice, an `o` argument *requires* code that tests for `-NoValue-`:

```
\IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
  do something when the optional argument is not present%
}{%
  do something else with #1 when the optional argument is specified%
}
```

And be careful with endlines.

There's already a built-in mechanism (you need a fairly recent version of LaTeX, though). This mechanism also deals with `\input filename`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\AddToHook{file/before}{\typeout{*** DEBUG: \CurrentFile}}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Just some random content.

\input{knuth}

\end{document}
```

However, you probably want to delay the addition of the DEBUG information after packages are loaded, because you get a lot of useless bits about the files input, for instance, by Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}

\AddToHook{file/before}{\typeout{*** DEBUG: \CurrentFile}}

\begin{document}

Just some random content.

\input{knuth}

\end{document}
```

The file `knuth.tex` contains some text and is useful for experiments such as this one.

Here's an excerpt of the console output (the tons of files loaded by Ti*k*Z are omitted)

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./marc.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-10-10>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
[...omissis...]
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
*** DEBUG: l3backend-pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./marc.aux)
*** DEBUG: supp-pdf.mkii
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
*** DEBUG: epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
*** DEBUG: epstopdf-sys.cfg
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
*** DEBUG: knuth.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/sample/common/knuth.tex)
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./marc.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on marc.pdf (1 page, 19830 bytes).
Transcript written on marc.log.
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight, it seems that there were two errors in play: Firstly, the two possible ways of applying ``\input{file}`` and ``\input file``, and secondly the ``xparse`` argument type confusion added during debugging.
Your answer adresses the second problem, and has me understand why my debugging process did not work as intended. Thank you very much for pointing out the hook to me as well.
Since your answer does not adress the full problem, I won't mark it as checked for now.

Comment: @marc I added the discussion.

Comment: Thank you, now it is an acceptable answer. When you state *fairly recent version [of LaTeX]*, what amount of time do you refer to? According to ``lthook-doc``, it should be present since 2021, right?

Comment: Do you by chance have a suggestion how I should redefine ``\input`` correctly within the ``xparse`` framework? @egreg

Comment: @marc You might use the deprecated argument type `g`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I'm afraid I have not been clear enough, in that I just used the optional argument during debugging. I actually want to replace the body for the original signature of ``\input``. I was trying to omit the argument types listed in section 1.8, since it states, "[they] are not recommended any longer [...]".
I found, however, that argument type ``u{ }`` works well for my case (Note the additional space). Do you see any drawbacks to that?